# magento miscellaneous scripts in header config retrieval

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Does anyone know what file or db would contain the data that is inputted in miscellaneous scripts in the design configuration of the back-end? I may have deleted some important script from there and I need to retrieve the data from a backup but I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that almost all the configuration stores in the table:
core_config_data
In this case:

```
SELECT * FROM magento.core_config_data where path like '%design/head/includes%';
```

Greetings